How to replace string in small part of the text after occurence of certain keyword
I have multiple Azure DevOps pipeline files with many stages like this:
...
- stage: 'qa'
  dependsOn:
  - dev
  condition: |
    and
    (
      condition1,
      condition2,
      ...,
      startswith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')
    )

# This needs to stay the same
- stage: 'uat'
  dependsOn:
  - dev
  condition: |
    and
    (
      condition1,
      condition2,
      ...,
      startswith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')
    )
...

Now we are updating all these files to new deployment strategy and I need to change two things - the dependsOn clause and the source branch refs/heads/development in the condition - but only for the qa stage.
The result should look like this
...
- stage: 'qa'
  dependsOn:
  - build
  condition: |
    and
    (
      condition1,
      condition2,
      ...,
      startswith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')
    )

# This needs to stay the same
- stage: 'uat'
  dependsOn:
  - dev
  condition: |
    and
    (
      condition1,
      condition2,
      ...,
      startswith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')
    )
...

I am able to do the first part quite easily - I know there is always just one item in that array. So this will work sed "/stage: 'qa'/{ n; n; s/dev/build/g }" pipeline.yaml
But the second part is harder, there can be multiple conditions and I don't exactly know how many lines to skip.
Is there any way how to tell sed to replace a string only in part of the file, lets say from 4 to 10 lines below occurrence of the stage: 'qa' string?

Use a YAML tool to manipulate YAML documents. yq is fairly popular and well supported.

Although the pipeline is yaml, that condition is not yaml so I would still need some text edit tool. I need to replace only that 'refs/heads/development' with 'refs/heads/main'

please update the question with all replacement details as well as the expected result

are you looking to replace all lines (within - stage: 'qa' block) that includes the string SourceBranch or is there an additional filter that needs to be considered? or will there only be a single line containing the string SourceBranch?

Updated. Replacing all lines containing particular source branch should be ok.

For structured data, use structure-aware processors, not text processors that can only manipulate the textual representation without seeing/understanding the underlying logic).

Although the pipeline is yaml, that condition is not yaml so I would still need some text edit tool.

You could use the YAML processor mikefarah/yq, which also has text-processing capabilities (applicable to the condition):
yq 'map(select(.stage == "qa").condition |= sub("refs/heads/development"; "refs/heads/main"))'

- stage: 'qa'
  dependsOn:
    - build
  condition: |
    and
    (
      condition1,
      condition2,
      ...,
      startswith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')
    )

# This needs to stay the same
- stage: 'uat'
  dependsOn:
    - dev
  condition: |
    and
    (
      condition1,
      condition2,
      ...,
      startswith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')
    )


Thank you for pointing me out. For regular ADO pipelines (the example array is located under key stages) I needed to update the command little bit: yq '(.stages.[] | select(.stage == "qa").condition) |= sub("refs/heads/development"; "refs/head/main")'

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E "/^- stage: 'qa'/{:a;N;/^\s*\)$/M"\!"ba
         s/(dependsOn:[^-]*- )\S+/\1build/
         s#(SourceBranch'], )'[^']*'#\1'refs/head/main'#}" file

Make a collection of the qa stage and then use substitution and back references to achieve the desired result.
N.B. The use of double quotes to enclose the sed commands. This makes it easier to include single quotes for matching and substitution. However it also causes the shell to do unexpected things, so the negation (!) needs to be escaped (see /.../M"\!"ba ) otherwise shell history is invoked. Also note the use of M flag when matching the end of stage collection.
